# Writing to an Output File

Tags: c++, c, error-handling

I am trying to output all of the combinations of various numbers in a set.  I have the program running and I have an excel output file that is created, but I cannot seem to get the results to print to the output file.  The line `fputs(num[i],fp)` seems to be the issue with the error

> Source.cpp(45): error C2664: 'int fputs(const char *,FILE *)' : cannot
>   convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const char *' 1>          Conversion
>   from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style
>   cast or function-style cast

```
for (j = 1; j <= n; j++)
{
   for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
   {
      temp = num[i];
      num[i] = num[i + 1];
      num[i + 1] = temp;
      print(num, n);
      fputs(num[i],fp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you have to pass `char*` you are passing an `int`.

```
fputs(std::to_string(num[i]).c_str(),fp);
```

This would solve the issue. You can check [`std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).

Answer (score 0):

In your `fputs` call, `num[i]` is an integer.  You need to convey it to a string and provide a punter to that string to fputs.  Or, if this is C++, maybe just use the `<<` operator.